# Help please - Dent in top tube of double butted aluminium frame

Tags: frames, safety, damage, aluminum

I have a ridgeback velocity which is labled as double butted aluminium. Around the middle of the toptube is a dent shown in the photo. There is also a short line above it which I can feel with my nail. Would it be safe to ride?

[image]

Comment: Just keep an eye on it.  It might eventually begin to fail with enough repeated stress, but that could be 100,000 miles from now.

Comment: Do you know how it got dented?

Comment: It helps that it's on the top tube, where it's easy to keep an eye on it and there are normally no lateral forces to speak of.  If it were on the down tube just above the bottom bracket, it might be more of a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's safe to ride. That "line" it's just a crack on the paint surface, I would suggest painting it with something like clear nail poslish jusft in case. A dent on a commuter bike is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

the dent looks small enough that it does not pose a safety risk, although a picture with something included for scale would help confirm that.